# Can a Mathematics Undergrad do a Ph.D. in Bioinformatics?

Tags: phd, mathematics, application, bioinformatics

I have a particular background, I studied biology and Chemistry in Highschool, some engineering in college, and I am now majoring in mathematics with a minor in computer science.

To some extent I feel like being able to do research is on my life goals bucket list. Diving into unexplored territory definitely excites me. So I somewhat feel I need to take advantage of the broad spectrum of fields I have knowledge of, although almost insignificant, it is still there. I thought maybe bioinformatics mixed with some data science algorithm research would be a good path to pursue. Would my prior experience in Biology give me an advantage? For example the ability to pick up technical biology concepts quicker?

Any insight and guidance on the topic would be appreciated.

Kind regards.

Comment: I also studied biology and chemistry in high school (and not thereafter), and in my opinion what I learned there is so little, compared with what biology or chemistry students learn at the university, that I would not consider it an advantage for moving to a field related to biology or chemistry. On the other hand, my background in mathematics might well give me an advantage in such a field.

Comment: Doesn't everyone study biology and chemistry at school?

Comment: Yes, let's just say I studied advanced Biology. For example, I know precisely what oxygen is for. I doubt everyone with a High School degree and college unrelated to biology does too.

Comment: Is this a question about US study?

Comment: @astronat This varies fairly wildly by location. It's quite possible (and indeed quite common) for someone with a maths degree in the UK to have studied no biology or chemistry at all since they were 16 years old.

Comment: @user3482749 yes, I know -- I am one of those people! But isn't a GCSE roughly equivalent to a US high school class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a range of different things covered by the broad terms "bioinformatics" and "computational biology".

Some bioinformaticians are (like myself) biologists who use a computer to carry out their experiments rather than a pipette.

Some bioinformaticians are genuinely informaticians - they are interested in how information is stored, organized and structured. They are into databases, data formats, the right types of metadata that need to be collected etc.

Some bioinformaticians are basically applied statisticians. Then it is all about the stats knowledge.

Finally some bioinformaticians develop and build algorithms and new methods to analyse data in new ways, or automate or performance optimise previously designed analyses. These people far more likely to be computer scientists.

This is before we even consider mathematical biologists and biological theorists.

---

None of these paths is closed to you. I am of the "biologist with a keyboard" breed of bioinformatician, and have taken on students from a CS background in the past, and would taken on students from the CS/maths background in the future. But you will have work to do to learn the biology, and you won't get very far in my lab without developing an expert level knowledge of at least the biological area your thesis is in. UK PhD students don't as a rule take any classes. But I have send CS background students to undergrad classes in the past.

On the other hand, you are probably perfectly placed for a PhD in an algorithm development and optimization lab. You'd need to learn some biology, but probably wouldn't find it so onerous.

However, in neither case do I think advanced level high-school biology would make much difference. Our biology undergrad requires chemistry, and recommends maths, but does not require biology at high-school

---

A final word of warning - biology still very much has a culture that the reason to do a PhD is to spend your life in that field. Not necessarily stay in academia (although some of the older faculty might still be reluctant to take on someone who doesn't want an academic career), but at least start with a desire to stay in some sort of bioinformatics. I'm not saying its a good thing, but it is a thing.

Comment: Thank you for the insight.

Answer (score 4):

Sure. There are many people who transitioned to Bioinformatics from a math background. As one example, there is a lot of machine learning being applied to various aspects of biology, and that could be a good fit for you.

But I would just caution that when choosing a Ph.D. topic, you should really think about what you want to do in the future, rather than what you've done in high school, or even taken a couple classes on in college. In a Ph.D. you'll anyway have to learn a lot about some very narrow topics and also (possibly) take some broad classes, so the fact that you know a bit extra about some biological concepts is not that important; a student without that background could probably catch up by reading a couple of books or taking a Coursera class, and both of you will be way behind an actual Biochemistry major (but still OK in the end). Pick your topic and advisor based on what sort of problems you want to solve for the next five years, and where you really see yourself ten years from now.

Comment: Caution: whether it's true that 'In a Ph.D. you'll anyway have to... take some broad classes' is country-dependent.

Comment: Dear @Jen, how important do you think choosing the "right" Ph.D. is? Most people don't end up working with anything related to their field anyways? So what difference does it make to work towards a Ph.D. in Bioinformatics, Data Science, Computational Science? All I want to do research publish a few papers, and get into the industry as a software engineer/developer.

Comment: @Dedekind This is not true for Bioinformatics. A far higher proportion of Bioinformaticians will stay in bioinformatics than CS grads stay in CS research. Sure, most people don't end up in academia long term (although its higher than many other subjects because to the shortage of qualified bioinformaticians), but its not a normal route to software engineer/developer. Data science is more common destination.

Comment: @DanielHatton True enough, thanks! Added a slight edit to my response.

Comment: @Dedekind - I guess I'm kind of confused about what you want, then. If you just want to work in industry as a SWE, you don't need a Ph.D., maybe not even a Master's (source: I was a senior SWE at a FAANG). If you want to do research, presumably you have some idea of what sort of research you'd like to spend 3-5+ years of your life doing, so my point was just that this is much more important than your coursework. Having said that, bioinformatics is pretty awesome, and I don't at all mean to deter you.

Answer (score 1):

> Would my prior experience in Biology give me an advantage? For example the ability to pick up technical biology concepts quicker?

No, not relative to most applicants for a PhD program in bioinformatics. There will be others who studied a quantitative field more related to biology than your math/CS pairing. Modern approaches to every area of biology involve increasingly quantitative methods. Graduates with undergraduate degrees in molecular biology, neuroscience, ecology, biochemistry, etc, are all potential candidates for bioinformatics PhD research, and they've all had an entire undergraduate education in biology beyond highschool. There will be students who initially pursued a medical/health profession and have taken courses in physiology. There will also be CS and stats undergrads who worked on biological or medical problems in their undergraduate research, people who primarily studied biology but with a minor in statistics/data science/bioinformatics, etc. High school biology, even "advanced" high school biology, will have you below the par for biology expertise in a bioinformatics field.

However, that doesn't mean it isn't possible for you to pursue bioinformatics (which itself is an *incredibly incredibly* broad area, the term itself has completely different meanings to different people). Instead, I think you'd be better off thinking about the ways that your prior experience in *mathematics* and *CS* gives you an advantage in bioinformatics, rather than a topic you last touched in high school. You probably have a lot to catch up on in biology, and that's just fine, as long as you realize how much there is to catch up on. We get quite a few questions over at Biology.SE from askers who learned about a bit of AI in their CS classes and now want to solve the big open problems in biology without taking the university-level courses in that area. They're a bit frustrating to deal with, and come off exactly like this physicist does: https://xkcd.com/793/